# How to avoid duplicate code

Tags: c++

As shown in the pictures, the two pieces of code are almost the same with only slight differences. Each duplicate might create some trouble, so if you encounter such situations, how are you supposed to solve them?

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6VdG.png)

[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzQha.png)

Comment: Write a helper function. Or - even better - lambda. Only do this if it's improving readability.

Comment: Don't post pictures of text - post text.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time using stackoverflow.

Comment: @Uchiha_Dawn please use the edit button and fix that.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the case.

In general you would add a function which knows both ways and return the value you need in every case.

So in your case you could do something like

```
bool myFuction(bool condition, int i, int k)
{
  if(condition == true)
  {
    return (i + MIN_SIZE + k < CK_SIZE); 
  }
  else
  {
    return (i - MIN_SIZE - k >= CK_SIZE);
  }
}
```

Now you can call `myFunction(..)`

The `bool condition` would be the condition wether you decide to use the first or the second way.